# How to Create directory inside the path that has set?

Tags: java, directory, dbf

I have convert file into DBF format. But i must save that dbf file into specific folder which has generated when i create directory. The common coding just written like this

```
import java.io.File;

// demonstrates how to create a directory in java
public class JavaCreateDirectoryExample
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    File dir = new File("/Users/al/tmp/TestDirectory");

    // attempt to create the directory here
    boolean successful = dir.mkdir();
    if (successful)
    {
      // creating the directory succeeded
      System.out.println("directory was created successfully");
    }
    else
    {
      // creating the directory failed
      System.out.println("failed trying to create the directory");
    }
  }
}
```

But, i would like change `"/Users/al/tmp/TestDirectory"` into a dynamic state **which i take it from the path JFileChooser that i've made**. Is there any possibilities to make it done? Thanks a lot

Comment: The path is just a String, so yes, you could use any String - for example from the args array (other options exist)

Comment: what does it mean by dynamic state? do you want this String `"/Users/al/tmp/TestDirectory"` to be dynamic ?

Comment: @Saif Yes. The dynamic state means that i change static directory with the path of i choose. Does it work?

Comment: yes its very simple because as @Romski said the path is just a `string` definitely you can change and chose it dynamically like any other string.

Comment: Friends, I just edited my question. Hopefully, my newly question could be answered. Thanks :D

Comment: Stackoverflow is not meant to replace reading manuals or tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the same variable, you can **instantiate it again**.

```
File dir = new File("/Users/al/tmp/TestDirectory");
boolean successful = dir.mkdir();

// Here we assign a new value by calling the constructor
dir = new File("/Users/al/tmp/AnotherTestDirectory");
// Next we create the new directory using the same method
boolean successful2 = dir.mkdir();
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing your quite new to Java. You should get in the habit of reading the [API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html#getSelectedFile()). It is your friend and will help answer these questions.

The `JFileChooser` can be used to get the selected `File` which can be used to get the path

JFileChooser API:

- getSelectedFile() - Returns the selected file.

File API:

- getAbsolutePath() - Returns the absolute pathname string of this abstract pathname.

...and some sample code

```
JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
int returnVal = chooser.showOpenDialog(parent);
if(returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
  String path = chooser.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath();
  File dir = new File(path);
  ....
}
```